# Verifying continuity by topology

Tags: general-topology

I want to show that sum of two continuous functions is continuous **using the topological definition only** .

I know the question could be answered by composing two continuous functions $(.,.):X\to\mathbb{K}^2$ and $+:\mathbb{K}^2\to\mathbb{K}$ over some infinite field $\mathbb{K}$ , and that has been answered several times in this site as well . But if I would want to use the basic open set definition , what would be the correct approach ?

Here's what I tried . Consider two continuous maps $f:X\to\mathbb{K}$ and $g:X\to\mathbb{K}$ where $X$ is some topological space . Then for all open sets $U$ in $\mathbb{K}$ , we have $f^{-1}(U)=\{x\in X:f(x)\in U\}$ and $g^{-1}(U)=\{x\in X:g(x)\in U\}$ are open in $X$ . We need to show $(f+g)^{-1}(U)=\{x\in X:(f+g)(x)\in U\}=\{x\in X:f(x)+g(x)\in U\}$ is open in $X$ . But how to relate the $f^{-1}(U),g^{-1}(U)$ with $(f+g)^{-1}(U)$ I don't understand . I have a feeling that the fact union of two open sets is open might be useful here .

Any help is appreciated .

Comment: You are using only addition, so maybe it's better to restate this for $\mathbb{K}$ a topological group rather then field.

Comment: Using the composition with the addition map on $\Bbb K^2$ which is **known** to be continuous (in a topological group or field) is by far the cleanest way. It also uses only basic topology (no metric arguments). What is wrong with it I wonder ? Self-torture?

Answer (score 1):

It would be easiest in my opinion to show that each point in $(f+g)^{-1}[U]$ is an interior point.  Assume without loss of generality that $0\in U$.

Assuming that your field is a topological field, you have a neighbourhood $U_0$ of $0$ which satisfies that $U_0^{-1}=U_0$, $U_0\subseteq U$ and $U_0+U_0\subseteq U$. Since $f$ is continuous, there exists a neighbourhood $V_1\subset X$ of $x_0$ such that $f[V_1]\subseteq U_0-g(x_0)$. Since $g$ is continuous, there exists a neighbourhood $V_2\subset X$ such that $g(x)\in g(x_0)+U_0$.

Combining these, you get for any $x\in V_1\cap V_2$ that

$$ f(x) +g(x)\subseteq U_0-g(x_0)+g(x)\subseteq U_0 +U_0\subseteq U. $$

Thus $x_0$ is an interior point of $(f+g)^{-1}[U]$, which implies continuity.

**You should convince yourself of the following:**

1. For an open set, $U$, $k+U$ is also open.
2. One can choose such a $U_0$, if $f(x_0)+g(x_0)=0$.
3. The last two facts can help you deal with the case when  $f(x_0)+g(x_0)\neq 0$.